# How to show kml file on mapbox

Tags: php, yii2, mapbox, kml, geojson

I want to show user uploaded kml file on Mapbox map.
one of the solution I found which is convert kml file to geojson but how to convert kml to geojson at runtime is second problem.

Answer (score 1):

Omnivore will let you display KML layers in Mapbox. You can parse it directly in Javascript like this:

```
omniore.kml.parse("<my kml string">);
```

or you could provide a KML URL just using

```
omnivore.kml("/my/url");
```

The former is probably easier for a user upload. These methods return layers that you can add to your Mapbox map like this:

```
omnivore.kml.parse("<my kml string>").addTo(map);
```

See https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore for more info.